# Default arguments in definition or declaration?

Tags: c++

Should the default arguments of a function/method reside in the definition or in the declaration? What is the best practice here and why?

```
class Test
{
    void method( bool flag /* = true */ ); // here?
};

void Test::method( bool flag /* = true */ ) // or here?
{

}
```

Comment: as you like, but it must be defined just once, and it must be visible to the compiler at the point of use. most generally applicable is to place default value in the first declaration. that's also most practical for reading interface.

Comment: by the way, instead of passing boolean arguments, consider using an appropriate enumeration type. `true` or `false` says very little at the call site.

Comment: What happened when you tried each option? Hint: The compiler will give you an error with one of the options.

Comment: Yeah, okay, but this was just a simple test class to clarify my question. I'm confused by thsi where to put it 'the correct way' in the header/first declaration to see the interface or in the definition as if it change you dont have to recompile the header etc.

Comment: @GregHewgill yes, i tried all possible options in ideone, thats why I'm asking here where to finally put the default parameter

Comment: ...and did you get any errors? What were the errors?

Comment: It is possible to put the default parameter EITHER in the declaration OR in the definition. Other options will cause an error as expected (g++ 4.8.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uhm, I don't have time to give a proper answer, but noting that C++ §8.3.6/6 says

> **”** Default arguments for a member function of a class template
>   shall be specified on the initial declaration of the member function within the class template

if one wants a single convention that works also for non-template code, one should better place defaults in the first declaration.

That's also generally most practical for readability.

---

For non-template code you can steadily add defaulting in subsequent redeclarations of a function, but it must be possible to omit actual arguments for all arguments to the right. Essentially that means decreasing the number of not-yet defaulted arguments. I fail to see the practical utility in this, or any rationale, and I've never seen it done in practice.

---

Anyway, regarding your statement [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471511/default-parameter-in-definition-or-declaration/24471650#comment37874969_24471511) “or in the definition as if it change you dont have to recompile the header”, note that a default value must be visible to the compiler at the place where the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

do it here

```
class Test
{
    void method( bool flag /* = true */ ); // here?
};
```

to keep the overview and make your life easier.